# what is the error in the powershell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-4.0, sccm

I have run the below command to get the output that when was my machine last patched but also need how to get the KB details too and how can I export in csv from SCCM.

```
$lastpatch=Get-HotFix | Sort-Object InstalledOn -Descending | Select-Object HotfixID, InstalledOn | Select-Object -first 1 
"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" -f $lastpatch.InstalledOn | Write-Output
```

When I run the below command to also get the HotfixID but I am not getting the result so can someone help me with it.

```
$lastpatch= Get-HotFix | Sort-Object InstalledOn -Descending | select-object -first 1 | Select-Object InstalledOn, HotfixID
"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" -f $lastpatch.InstalledOn,$lastpatch.HotfixID | Write-Output
```

Comment: From a quick look I see you call `-f` with two values, but you only have one placeholder in your string.

Comment: Hello @marsze , I am new to powershell so can you tell me how should I correct this issue like shall  remove $lastpatch.HotfixID because I need to time and HotFixID as output

Answer (score 0):

To include the HotfixID, you can make use of a calculated property to have the `Select-Object` return an object with both wanted properties into the variable `$lastPatch`.
Once you have that object, it is easy to export to csv:

```
$lastpatch = Get-HotFix | 
    Sort-Object InstalledOn -Descending | 
    Select-Object -First 1 | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'InstalledOn'; Expression = {"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" -f $_.InstalledOn}},
                  HotfixID

# Output on screen
$lastPatch

# output to csv file
$lastPatch | Export-Csv -Path 'Path\To\lastpatch.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```